# Simple neural network "calibration" (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, perceptron, calibration

I'm getting started with neural networks and this kind of stuff, I understood how a `perceptron` works and the logic behind `feed-forward and backpropagation` mechanisms and I am now trying to write a simple multi-layer network with 3 neurons (2 in a hidden layer and 1 as output) which *should* be enough to execute a `xor operation`.

I implemented it in Python (using v3.6.1 now) this way:

```
import numpy as np

class Neuron():

    def __init__(self, n, w = None, b = None):
        #np.random.seed(46144492)
        #np.random.seed(23)
        self.weights = 2 * np.random.random((n)) - 1 if w == None else np.array(w)
        self.bias = 2 * np.random.random() - 1 if b == None else b
        self.learning_rate = 0.1
        self.weights_error = []
        for i in range(n):
            self.weights_error.append(0)
        self.bias_error = 0

    def learning_factor(self, output):
        return output * (1 - output)

    def fire(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        weighted = []
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            weighted.append(inputs[i] * self.weights[i])
        weighted = np.array(weighted)
        return self.fire(weighted.sum() + self.bias)

    def adjust(self, n_weights):
        for i in range(n_weights):
            self.weights[i] -= self.weights_error[i]
        self.bias -= self.bias_error

class HiddenNeuron(Neuron):

    def calc_error(self, inputs, output, next_layer, number_in_layer):
        error = 0
        for n in range(len(next_layer)):
            error += next_layer[n].delta * next_layer[n].weights[number_in_layer - 1]
        derivative = self.learning_factor(output)
        self.delta = error * derivative
        self.weights_error = []
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            self.weights_error.append(self.delta * inputs[i] * self.learning_rate)
        self.bias_error = self.delta * self.learning_rate


class OutputNeuron(Neuron):

    def calc_error(self, inputs, output, expected):
        error = output - expected
        derivative = self.learning_factor(output)
        self.delta = error * derivative
        self.weights_error = []
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            self.weights_error.append(self.delta * inputs[i] * self.learning_rate)
        self.bias_error = self.delta * self.learning_rate

# Network
n1, n2 = HiddenNeuron(2), HiddenNeuron(2)
n3 = OutputNeuron(2)
# Training data
training_set_in = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
training_set_out = [0, 1, 1, 0]
# Training cycles
for i in range(10000):
    for i in range(len(training_set_in)):
        # Feed-forward
        n1_out = n1(training_set_in[i])
        n2_out = n2(training_set_in[i])
        n3_in = [n1_out, n2_out]
        n3_out = n3(n3_in)
        # Backpropagation
        n3.calc_error(n3_in, n3_out, training_set_out[i])
        n2.calc_error(training_set_in[i], n2_out, [n3], 2)
        n1.calc_error(training_set_in[i], n1_out, [n3], 1)
        n1.adjust(2)
        n2.adjust(2)
        n3.adjust(2)
# "New" cases (test)
for new in [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]:
    print(n3([n1(new), n2(new)]))
```

As you can see I use the sigmoid function as activation function and I haven't implemented the momentum yet (I have still to get how it works).

The network works, in most cases. But I found some cases in which it outputs some strange values (see for example the two random seeds I commented in the Neuron class constructor). This two cases are solved if I increase the Neuron.learning_rate (for example set it to 10), but still some other exceptions come up (couldn't find seeds for these, I'm sorry... But they're quire frequent, just run the code for 10 or 20 times and you'll see some).

The question is: Why is this happening? Is my network too "small"/simple? I thought 3 neurons would be enough. Or is it just a problem of "calibration" (don't know how this is called, I mean the process of adjusting the learning rate factor and the momentum, which here is absent)? Or did I even commit any mistakes? I can't really figure out.

**EDIT:** I'm training the net with all possible cases and then trying it with the same cases just to verify if it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's OK as neural network's performance depends on its initial state, that is, the weights and biases. In your case, the weights and biases start out randomised, and thus depend on the seed. There are even special [techniques](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/momentum.pdf)<sup>1</sup> to reduce this effect, such as [weight normalisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47590/what-are-good-initial-weights-in-a-neural-network) (also google this, there are some interesting papers on this topic).

---

1. link taken from http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap5.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer `:)`. I will look into it